# Java file save issue in Sublime Text3 on CentOS7

Tags: java, centos, sublimetext3

I'm a newbie developer using Sublime Text3 on CentOS7.
My first try to write some JAVA file is like below.

```
package com.javatools.git;

public class FirstSource {
        public static void main(string[] args){
                system.out.println("Hello World");
        }
}
```

After that, I'd try to save this file as `FirstSource.java`.
Then always below message pops up.

> "Unable to save ~/git_tutorial/git_repo/FirstSource.java
>    Error: permission denied"

It seems that the permission or something else related with the right of Sublime Text might be a cause of this. If you guys have similar experience with that, let me know that answer.

Thanks,

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l ~/git_tutorial/git_repo/` ?

Comment: I would make sure you have write permissions for that directory. Doing the command ThorbjørnRavnAndersen said will show that information.

Comment: **Total 0** after `ls -l ~/git_tutorial/git_repo/`. Yeah, something goes wrong. Also I got an answer "chmod". Saving done after `chmod a+rw ~/git_tutorial/git_repo/` Thanks, @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen @BinaryBuilder